# Pointers of abstract parent class pointing to derived class objects in 2D array C++

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, parent, derived-class

I have a superclass Human (which is abstract), of which child is a derived class of. I'm trying to make a 2D array of pointers which will point to some type of human. I'm trying to then fill in the coordinates of this array with some derived class of Human, like child. However, when I try the following code; I keep getting a segmentation fault, and I can't figure out why?

```
Human* map[rows][col]; // rows and col are globally defined values of 8
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
    map[i][j] = NULL;
  }
}

Child child1, child2; // child is a derived class of Human

map[0][4] = &child1;
map[7][4] = &child2;
```

(I first initilise them all to zero because I only want some of them to point to derived classes).

Comment: You haven't included enough code to tell for certain, but most likely you're putting in objects which are local to a function, and then later trying to use those pointers after the objects' lifetimes have ended.

Comment: @aschepler I'm not yet far with this - but in the next few lines I do try read through the array and if a child object is found - print out something specific. I'm confused why the objects wouldn't exist here though?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It's hard to suggest anything useful with bits and pieces of code.

Comment: What is the error

Comment: @JakeFreeman a segmentation fault